# set header for drawer navigation

Tags: react-navigation

I tried to set header in react navigation v5 by setting options without any change

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName='...'
>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name='...'
    component={Component}
    options={{ title: 'My home' }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

is there a way I could have my react navigation header in drawer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** The latest version of drawer navigator now has a header (can be shown with `headerShown: true`)

Drawer Navigator doesn't provide a header.

If you want to show headers in drawer screens, you have 2 options:

1. Provide your own header component. You can use header from libraries such as [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/appbar-header.html)
2. Nest a Stack Navigator in each drawer screen where you want to show a header.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the solution, however did not find any nice way to wrap up every component automatically with custom header. So I ended up creating HOC component and wrapping each `component` for every screen.

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

const NavHeader = props => {
 // ... NavHeader code goes here 
};

export const withHeader = Component => {
  return props => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <NavHeader {...props} />
        <Component {...props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
};
```

Then in your Drawer you do:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
      component={withHeader(DashboardContainer)} // <--- Wrap it around component here.
    />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a simple example with react navigation 5:

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can find about the navigation to a screen in a nested navigator in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) and [you can try this example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Nesting%20navigators%20%C2%B7%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnest-navigators.js)